# Coded UI Test Builder could not find a running emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I'm unable to run Coded UI Test Builder. I'm going to implement UI tests for the Windows Phone app. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and created simple test project and added Coded UI Test project. However, an error occurs during launch "Generate Code for Coded UI Tests...". Windows Phone 8.1 emulator is launched, but the error still occurs.

[image: Error on launch Coded UI Test Builder]

Also, I tried to launch standalone "codedUiTestBuilder.exe". It cannot recognize control in emulator at all. It recognizes only main window of the emulator, but nothing more.

Followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx) manual, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this issue also, what ended up fixing the problem was creating another Solution for my Coded UI Test Project. Separating it out from the App solution seemed to be a workaround for this problem.

I do not know what the underlying cause was.